# How do I fix this error?: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I have been working on this code for hours and cannot figure out this part. The program is supposed to be a tic tac toe game and somewhere I went wrong in my 2d array, as I keep getting this error. I could also use help on how to get the random generator to find a specific row and column.

Here is my code so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = 3;
        int col = 3;
        int[][] grid = new int[rows][col];

        fillGrid(grid);
        computerTurn(grid);
    }//end main

    public static void fillGrid(int[][] grids) {
        //int [][] grids = new int [3][3];
        for (int r = 0; grids.length < 3; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; grids[r].length < 3; c++) {
                grids[r][c] = 0;
            }
        }
        printGrid(grids);
    }

    public static void printGrid(int[][] x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < x[0].length; y++) {
                System.out.print(x[i][y] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void computerTurn(int[][] mygrid) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int rows = 3;
        int col = 3;
        //int [][] grid = new int [rows][col];
        //mygrid [rows][col] = random.nextInt(4);
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                //mygrid [rows][col] = random.nextInt(2);
                if (mygrid[r][c] == 0) {
                    //mygrid [r][c] = random.nextInt(3);
                    mygrid[rows][col] = 1;
                }
                /*if (mygrid [r][c] != 0) {
                    //mygrid [rows][col] = random.nextInt(3);
                    mygrid [r][c] = 1;
                }*/
            }
        }
        printGrid(mygrid);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fillGrid()` is not necessary - `int` table elements are initialized to `0` by default.

Comment: Break down the work that needs to be done in `computerTurn`. 1. Generate a random row and column index (in range [0,2]!) 2. Check if the cell is empty 3. Repeat the procedure until you find an empty cell.

Comment: `for (int r = 0; r < grids.length; r++) {` and `for(int c = 0; c < grids[r].length; c++) {`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to know on which line you the `indexOutOfBoundsException` is being thrown at. From the `: 3` at the end of the exception, we can know that somewhere in your code `someArr[3]` is being referenced on an array despite `someArr.length < 4`.

Your termination condition on the nested loop in `fillGrid` has some issues:

```java
for (int r = 0; grids.length < 3; r++) {
    /* Loop never enters, because grids.length = 3 */
    for (int c = 0; grids[r].length < 3; c++) {
        /* Loop also never enters, because grids[r].length = 3 */
        grids[r][c] = 0;
    }
}
```

I think you mean to have:

```java
for (int r = 0; r < grids.length; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < grids[r].length; c++) {
        grids[r][c] = 0;
    }
}
```

I also suggest replacing your loop in `computerTurn` with termination statements like this, so the method supports arrays of any length.

With regard to your exception, once you locate where it's occurring, try to print the length of the array that you're trying to access and print the index that you're trying to access. This way you can move on to debugging why the value is wrong.